# Django Rest Framework: Page Not Found 404 Error while displaying an image

Tags: python, django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use images in my api using django rest framework but I am still getting the error 404 Page not found. Here's my code -

**Models.py**

```
class SampleModel(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SampleModel
        fields = ['text', 'image']
```

**views.py**

```
class SampleView(generics.ListAPIView, generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = SampleModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SampleSerializer
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [path('sample/', SampleView.as_view(), name='sample')]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets")
MEDIA_URL = '/assets/'
```

I tried googling the solution on google and tried few things too but I still get the same error.
I tried to create another project and used the same code as above and it is still giving me the same error.

[image: The error I get while accessing the file.]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the image field you added to the serializer. I don't think that's required and that might be causing something unexpected because the rest of the code looks good.

Comment: I tired doing that but nothing happened. It is giving me the same error. I have been stuck on this for last 3 days

Comment: I tried using a new project and used the same code. It reproduces the error.

Comment: @Sarthak I think I see something. The screenshot you attached doesn't show any URL for ^assests/, Django only found URLs for admin/ api/vi/ and api/v2. Where have you added the urlpatterns media URL? It should be in the main urls.py file

Comment: I did some more debugging and found that you need to add static function in the project's urls.py and not the app's urls.py. I don't know why but it worked when I did that.